# Apt-get update hangs in 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 64bit. apt-get update hangs here..

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]                               
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94.5 kB]       
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [92.2 kB]
Fetched 281 kB in 2s (126 kB/s)
```

Don't know what it's doing, but top reports a new process:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                 
 2476 root      20   0  134232  37976   9708 R  99.7  0.1   3:36.12 appstreamcli
```

The graphical updater doesn't make it to the end either.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens when you try to change to other mirrors?

Comment: Its a bug, the same problem is happening on my machine. Please report it here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/774985/apt-get-update-hangs-in-16-04#

Comment: After selecting another mirror it tries to download the list of packages and hangs at some point. The 'appstreamcli' process is again in the process list and never terminates

Comment: @SeverusTux where are bugs reported? You posted the link of the question

Comment: @Frank I am sorry. Here it is : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1583862

Comment: Not only is this hanging the system, even new installs hang at this point making it impossible to complete an install.